# Usage of Coalesce or Case statement in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api, coalesce

How to use `coalesce`  or `case statement` in JPA 2 using CriteriaBuilder

For many records initiatedBy will be empty and as a result employeeName will be null for those records. I would like to display **System Generated** if `employeeName` is null for those projects where initiatedBy employee is null in database table.

I have the following relationships in Entities

**Project**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROJECT") 
public class Project {

@Id
@Column(name = "PROJECTID")
private Long projectId;
....
....

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEENUMBER", referencedColumnName = "EMPLOYEENUMBER")
private Employee empNumber;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "INITIATEDBY", referencedColumnName = "EMPLOYEENUMBER")
private Employee initiatedBy;
```

**Employee**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEES")
public class Employee {

@Id
@Column(name = "EMPLOYEENUMBER")
private String employeeNo;

@Column(name = "EMPLOYEENAME")
private String employeeName;
.....
.....

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "empNumber")
private Set<Project> employeeProject;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "initiatedBy")
private Set<Project> employeeInitiatedBy;

.....
```

in **DAOImpl** class I have

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Project> c = cb.createQuery(Project.class);
Root<Project> emp = c.from(Project.class);
c.orderBy(cb.desc(emp.get("projectNo")));
c.select(emp);

TypedQuery<Project> q =  entityManager.createQuery(c);
```

I have tried with

```
Coalesce<String> coalesce = cb.coalesce();
coalesce.value(emp.<String>get("employeeName"));
coalesce.value("System Generated");
```

However when I run, I am getting exception as

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve attribute 
[employeeName] against path
```

Any help on this is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First problem is possible misunderstanding in usage of JPA entities as a query result. When entities are used as result of query, they mirror state of database. Replacing `Employee.empName` with value other than one in database contradicts with that.

Until certain point that can be achieved via [CriteriaBuilder.construct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#construct%28java.lang.Class,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Selection...%29). Result objects (which can also be entities) are created via constructor which must take all the select items as an argument. Unfortunately that does not play well together with object graph (`Project` and connected `Employee` in this case).

Second problem is that in following `get("employeeName")` is called for `Project`, and it does not have such an attribute:

```
Root<Project> emp = c.from(Project.class);
...
coalesce.value(emp.<String>get("employeeName"));
```

In general coalesce can be used as follows (but because of what was said above, this does not alone solve problem):

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<String> c = cb.createQuery(String.class);
Root<Employee> emp = c.from(Employee.class);

CriteriaBuilder.Coalesce<String> coalesce = cb.coalesce();
coalesce.value(emp.<String>get("employeeName"));
coalesce.value("System Generated");
c.select(coalesce);

TypedQuery<String> q =  em.createQuery(c);
```

Comment: Mikko so the correct way of using `coalesce` is `coalesce.value(emp.<String>get("employeeName"));`?

Comment: Not in this case, because in given code, despites it's name emp does not refer to Employee. It is Root<Project> emp. Employee does have employeeName attribute, Project doesn't have. I will add example of coalesce usage to answer.